# Using newest 2013 MS cc compiler into older visual studio 2010 interface?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compiler-construction, ide

I wanted to know if anybody had the experience of configuring this : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41151
into visual studio 2010 ?

I have only Windows Vista on some of my machines; and I'd like to code using a 2012 or 2013 compiler. I know visual studio is greatly configurable and can plug various compilers (like sony for PS Vita is providing a configuration for gcc based compiler in visual studio).

VS 2012 and 2013 express cannot be installed on Vista. But I see no reason why the compiler; a purely command line tool, wouldn't work on Vista. (because it wouldn't dare to need that darn `K32GetModuleInformation` thingie. I bet MS called this function for purely phony purposes of forcing people to upgrade their OS)

thanks !

ps : of course a trick to make vs 2013 express (for desktop) installable on vista would also be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't find a solution and would to try it yourself, I suggest you manually edit the toolset in the project file, hit build, and lookup where the error is generated. That tells you what is wanted, and in which location - I'm 99% sure it will want the toolset definition in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets: and that just contains files that tell where the binaries are. So maybe that is all there is to it: extract CTP, add toolset.props and .targets files.

Comment: btw should you still be using VS2008, for that version I found a solution for VS2010 that might work for VS2013 as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603653/how-to-use-visual-studio-2010-c-tools-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: @stijn: thanks :) so it seems doable. only trick, install the CTP on another machine first to copy the installed executables. because otherwise on the vista machine itself; impossible to extract them from the installer :'( and the installer quits early because they say they dont find VS2013. doh

Comment: a lot of installers can be extracted using WinRAR/7Zip/.. also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe